# Regular Expression Google Form only numbers in a range

Tags: regex, forms, google-forms

I have this regex formula in a google forms field. It validates that users don't input decimals,".0" or ",00" because it messes up my calculations on submits.

[image]

Now i need to add to this validation a minimum number. So that users don't input a number under 120. Is this possible?

If its possible, is also posible to put a max number, so the input can only be in a certain range. Maybe 120>X<1000

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^(1[2-9][0-9]|[2-9][0-9]{2})$
```

This regex will only allow whole integer numbers from 120 to 999.

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mW8yP9/2)

Explanation:

- `1[2-9][0-9]` - Alternative 1: `1` followed by `2-9` digit range, followed by `0-9` digit range
- `|` - alternation operator
- `[2-9][0-9]{2}` - Alternative 2: `2-9` digit range, followed by 2 occurrences of (due to `{2}`) `0-9` digit range.

Here is a [Google Forms demo showing this regex works](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1nM02nNWSMP-gaIo5yc7XocTIcKSmaP-gYlfSgluhFcI/viewform?usp=send_form)

Comment: Genius!!! Could you give me the example with only the minimum 120, without maximum 999 please?

Comment: You just need to add `[0-9]{4,}` alternative: `^(1[2-9][0-9]|[2-9][0-9]{2}|[0-9]{4,})$`. However, I wonder why you do not just use the numeric field type? You can indicate a *Greater than* condition there. Have a look at [how the numeric field works (the middle *Second ? - 120+ - Numeric* option)](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1nM02nNWSMP-gaIo5yc7XocTIcKSmaP-gYlfSgluhFcI/viewform).

Comment: Your [form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1nM02nNWSMP-gaIo5yc7XocTIcKSmaP-gYlfSgluhFcI/viewform) can NOT be viewed any more. You must have accidentally closed it. Could you please look into it? Thanks.